# error using restrict keyword

Tags: c++, c, optimization, restrict-qualifier

In the following example:

```
void foo (double *ptr)
{
     const double * restrict  const restr_ptr=ptr;
}
```

I get this  error:

```
error: expected a ";"      const double * restrict  const restr_ptr=ptr;
                                                      ^
```

I compile with -std=c99, using gcc 3.4

Any Ideas?

Comment: It compiles for me just fine. Have you got a recent version of GCC?

Comment: That code compiles for me on Sun C 5.8 and GCC 3.4.6. Comeau online only complains about the unused variable declaration. Please provide more details about your environment.

Comment: ... but Comeau was in C99 mode. When I put it in C++ mode, it complains about the same thing.

Comment: I should have been more specific about what "the same thing" meant in my last comment. In C++ mode, Comeau says it expects a semicolon, just like Enigma's compiler.

Comment: That's not valid C++ code therefore it wont work in C++ mode. restrict is restricted to C99.

Comment: @Ben look more closely at my question. I specified -std=c99 for the compiler. @Rob Kennedy already provided a solution.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

In C++, `restrict` is not a keyword (except for [Microsoft extensions](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/5ft82fed.aspx)). It doesn't mean what it does in C. It looks as though you tried to apply C99 mode to your C++ compiler. Use a C compiler to compile C code, and use a C++ compiler to compile C++. Neither language is a subset of the other.

Comment: Agh, that explain. I cannot compile using C compiler as I use C++ features where restrict is used. What's the workaround, if any?

Comment: Try `__restrict`. Looks like it's a GCC extension as well as a Microsoft extension. Consider abstracting it with a macro so non-GCC, non-MS compilers don't choke on it.